# Bedroom light turns on when hallway light is turned with new Smart Switch

Tags: wiring, switch

I replaced a normal dimmable light switch in a bedroom with a smart dimmable light switch. But now when I turn on the dimmable normal three-way hallway light switch it also turns on the bedroom light, however the light in the bedroom is not as powerful. When the hallway lights are set a full brightness the bedroom is probably at 90% brightness (even though the light switch is off in the bedroom). When the hallway lights are set at 15% brightness, the bedroom is at about 5% brightness (even though the light switch is off in the bedroom). When I turn the switch on in the bedroom it works normally; and the switch in the bedroom has no effects on the hallway lights. I'm guessing this has to do something with the neutral wire and the smart switch in the bedroom drawing power from the hallway lights when the hallway lights are turning on. This is a newly constructed house and all light bulbs are LED throughout, and all switches are dimmable.
I've installed other smart switches in the house and haven't come across this problem in any other rooms.
Did the contractor wire this wrong, and/or its acting like a 4-way switch?
Or is the neutral wire in the bedroom getting more power from the hallway lights when  they are turned on? If so, is there a way to stop this from happening, besides getting rid of the smart switch? I didn't have this problem when the normal dimmable switch was installed which was not connected to the neutral wire.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! Please [edit] your post to include some formatting - it's hard to digest that wall of text. Once you've done that, take the [tour] and read through the [help] while you're waiting on an answer so you can learn how to get the most out of this site, since it's a bit different than most discussion forums.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?